# What is the runtime of this pseudocode?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, runtime-analysis, pseudocode

I need help figuring out the runtime of the following pseudocode. I believe it is O(|E| + |V|), but I'm not totally sure...

```
graphFunction(graph):
     q = Queue()
     for vertex in graph:
         q.enqueue(vertex)
     while q is not empty():
         v = q.dequeue()
         for  every outgoing edge of v:
             edge.weight++
         for every incoming edge of v:
             edge.weight++
```

Comment: The answer might depend on the implementation of Queue.

Comment: Show your argumentation assuming queue operations taking constant/unit time.